# Is there a way to prevent iTunes store URLs from launching the iTunes app in OS X?

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-store

[Links to iTunes store](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker) items like apps, launched from from Safari on OS X, first

1. open a web page for the item, and then
2. launch iTunes and open the corresponding page there.

Is there a way to represent the second step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for...

http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-stop-itunes-web-links-from-opening-itunes/